# Reverting back JQuery from noConflict mode to its original state

Tags: jquery

How can I revert back jQuery from noConflict mode to standard mode.

I would like to use two versions of JQuery on one side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.jqSite = jQuery.noConflict(true);      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.new.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- The following code is using $ and jQuery from jquery new -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="some-script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- reverting back to original jquery lib used on the site -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict(true)
  $ = jQuery = window.jqSite;
</script>
```

Using the above code, $ and jQuery variables are not resolved correctly and I get error "$ is not a function".

Any ideas ?

Comment: On first glance, that looks like it should work.  That's also a strange error to get.  It implies that one of the files you are including is trying to use `$()` but it's not defined, making me wonder if a) `jquery.new.js` is not defining `$` correctly or b)   `jquery.new.js` assumes `$` is already defined.  Do you know what line is the error reported for?  If you remove the last `<script>` block do you still get that error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using two versions of jQuery on one site sounds like a bad idea that will lead to confusion over time.  Is it possible to fix some-script.js to work with the same version of jQuery as the rest of the site?

That being said, it sounds like the $ and jQuery reference errors are coming from some-script.js.  Could you post your real code somewhere for us to look at?

One issue I can think of is that you should make sure that some-script.js creates a new reference to its version of jQuery so that any functions it creates that reference jQuery continue to use jQuery from jQuery.new.js after window.$ and window.jQuery are reset to window.jqSite.